# References for completions of finite group tensor categories

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, monoidal-categories, quantum-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\operatorname{Vec}_G$ be the tensor category of $G$-graded vector spaces (or, if you prefer, $\pi_{\le 2}(BG)$).

The completion $\overline{\operatorname{Vec}_G}$ of $\operatorname{Vec}_G$ is a 2-category with

- 0-morphisms Frobenius algebra objects in $\operatorname{Vec}_G$
- 1-morphisms bimodule objects in $\operatorname{Vec}_G$
- 2-morphisms morphisms of bimodule objects

Results of Ostrik [https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202130] give a constructive way of computing these 2-categories.

Simple example: For $G = \mathbb Z/2$, there is exactly one non-trivial indecomposable algebra object $a$.  The tensor category of endomorphisms of $a$ is isomorphic to another copy of $\operatorname{Vec}_{\mathbb Z/2}$.  There is a single indecomposable bimodule object connecting $a$ to the trivial algebra object 1.  The overall 2-category $\overline{\operatorname{Vec}_{\mathbb Z/2}}$ could be described as "shaded Ising" or "shaded $SU(2)_2$".  It has a symmetry which exchanges 1 and $a$, and this symmetry explains/implements the well-known $e$-$m$ symmetry of $\operatorname{Vec}_{\mathbb Z/2}$ (a.k.a. toric code).

**Question:** For which (if any) $G$ has the 2-category $\overline{\operatorname{Vec}_G}$ been worked out in the literature?

By "worked out" I mean, at minimum, that the fusion rules between all 1-morphisms (bimodule objects) are described explicitly.  Using the Ostrik reults, this calculation is straightforward but tedious.  (I've done the $G = S_3$ case.)  I'm hoping that instead of writing an appendix I can cite another paper.